# Asp.net-mvc PlaceHolder, how to use it?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, controls, placeholder

I have my Master Page with some Html.RenderPartial and a random ContentPlaceHolder inside it, more or less like this:

```
<body>

<% Html.RenderPartial("Controls/Menu"); %>
<% Html.RenderPartial("Controls/GenericControl"); %>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MyContent" runat="server" />

</body>
```

At the moment in the *Menu.ascx* file I have a list of buttons. In the *GenericControl.ascx* file there are some buttons to manage the content.
And I have as many views as buttons in my Menu and the content is so described:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MyContent" runat="server">
<div>Some divs here</div>
<asp:Content>
```

And here's my problem.
I would like to put another *asp:Content* in my views, I don't want to link it in the Master Page but in the GenericControl.
Obviously I can't use the ContentPlaceHolder. I'm trying to use the PlaceHolder instead but I'm having some problems to find how to use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using Asp.net MVC, you should not use server controls (the ones which starts with `<asp: />`).

Do define Placeholders in asp.net mvc using Razor engine, you can do this:

In _Layout

```
@RenderSection("header", required: false)
```

In view

```
@section header {
   <h1>Hello World</h1>
}
```

To make it work in web forms view engine, probably you have to replace `@` with `<% %>`

Comment: My problem, in few words, is that they gave me that files and they said "Make this site work and make it good looking!"
And I'm still learning how this _logic_ works.

Anyway thanks for the answers and I'll try what you suggested.